How to check if translation exists in Next-intl
en.json:
{
  "About": {
    "title": "About us"
  }
}

About.jsx:
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';
function About() {
  const t = useTranslations('About');
  return <h1>{t('title')}</h1>;
}

This demo code in the official document works fine,
but if we pass a string to t that does not match an existing key, we get a MISSING_MESSAGE error in the console.
Like this:
MISSING_MESSAGE Error in console
I found issue 448 and the related issue 88,
but neither of them seems to solve the issue completely.
So I wonder if there is an elegant and robust solution to check if a translation key exists.

When translation is missing it results string in {page}.{key} format, so you can do something like this
const t = useTranslations('About');
const hasTitle = t.raw('title') !== `About.title`;

You can go step further moving it to your custom hook, to add has method
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

type RequiredFields<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>;

type ExtendedTranslation<T = string> = ReturnType<typeof useTranslations<T>> & {
  has?(key: T): boolean;
};

export function useTranslation(page: string) {
  const t: ExtendedTranslation = useTranslations(page);
  t.has = (key) => t.raw(key) !== `${page}.${key}`;
  return t as RequiredFields<ExtendedTranslation, 'has'>;
}


This is indeed a solution. I was just expecting next-intl to have a native method for detecting if a translation key exists. But it seems that there is no method that can meet this requirement. Anyway, thank you.

if you're using TypeScript you can add that checking to global.d.ts
import en from './messages/en.json';

type Messages = typeof en;

declare global {
  interface IntlMessages extends Messages {}
}


https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/workflows/typescript
